# Do 22.5 degree pipe fittings exist?

Tags: pipe, fitting

I'm trying to make a triple-monitor stand using steel plumbing pipe, as I've seen this done by others in the past. Most designs call for 45 degree pipe elbows for the side monitor arms, but this seems to be way too extreme of an angle for my purposes. I've been unable so far to find any other angle sizes of pipe elbows.

Comment: While I'm answering this question, I also suspect it should be closed as off topic (hobby project).

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but why not use a pair of 90 degree elbows to make an adjustable hinge. The first elbow would go vertical, and the second would return it horizontal. Then you can create any angle you'd like.

Comment: Good answer, I hadn't thought of doing that. I could even use 3 90's to keep the pipe lines relatively straight.

Comment: Only problem would be getting the angle right when gluing the pipes.

Comment: You could leave them loose and adjustable. You could also have a set screw or try something like thread lock to fix it in position non-permanently.

Comment: Set screw sounds great, now to find one :)

Answer (score 1):

They exist, [though maybe not in the material you would like](http://www.mcmaster.com/#plastic-pipe-fittings/=l5w5uy)

I would go to a plumbing/HVAC supplier and ask.